# Abnormal usage for memory

Tags: server, ram, memory-usage, vps

These days, my **linux VPS** is very slow, for that I've installed `htop` package using `apt-get` to see what is happening to my server.

When I opened `htop`, I see that my server is using approximatively `700 MB` of memory. I tried to `reboot` the **VPS**, but nothings changed, the ram usage is still high for nothing
Here's what I get with `htop` :

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNO9M.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ZQj.png)

And here's what I get with the command `free -h`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1,0G       933M        69M         0B       4,3M       219M
-/+ buffers/cache:       709M       292M
Swap:         1,3G       292K       1,3G
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have a total of 1GB from which 292MB are free. Depending on what you are running, I would say that is normal. The 69MB are without the cache portion which can be freed at any time when needed.

To see which programs are really using the most memory, you should sort by the RES column in htop (hit F6 for sorting).

But if you really have memory problems, you may also check if you have any tmpfs mounted. tmpfs resides in the page cache, so free doesn't report it as used memory and you might actually have less than 292MB.

---

EDIT: Forking services such as Apache tend to use the most memory, especially when the number of client requests goes up. Try reducing the number of threads, maybe switch from prefork MPM to worker MPM (see http://codebucket.co.in/apache-prefork-or-worker/) or use a more light-weight server such as Nginx (see comments below this answer).

Comment: But before, free -h was displaying me only 300M used, and the VPS were fast

Comment: As I said: launch htop and sort by RES. Only that way you'll know what's sucking up your memory. Also keep an eye on the swap value because that's what makes a system *really* slow.

Comment: Here's it. Is it coming from console-kit-daemon ? http://i.imgur.com/sbyqEQ1.png

Comment: Swap value is 0, so I haven't problems with this

Comment: Are you using any graphical login manager? I suppose not. In that case you should disable console-kit-daemon. No idea why it's started anyway. It cosumes about 3MB per thread which isn't much, but sums up to about 192MB with 64 processes.

Comment: I've killed it using kill command, but the ram is still at hight usage - 697MB
I really don't know why my VPS use too much ram for nothing http://i.imgur.com/I9JRVa8.png

Comment: Yeah, probably most of the 3MB are shared code memory. Again, look what process is next in the list. But I guess the running programs are not really your issue. Have a look at the output of `df -h`. Sometimes /tmp is mounted as tmpfs/shm and may fill up quickly.

Comment: I've seen the next process - there's nothing that's using a lot of memory.
Here's the output of `df -h` http://i.imgur.com/ZJOmHvv.png

Comment: You have three tmpfs, but they are not used much. Next thing to check is whether you have HugePages enabled. and how big they are (`cat /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages` and `grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo`). If that's not your problem, I don't know what it is.

Comment: I think that's not the problem `:(` http://i.imgur.com/yVhQxfX.png
but thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Well, I don't know *what* is using your RAM, but when it's not really changing and the system isn't swapping either, I would say it's not the main reason why your VPS is slow. Performance drops can also come from increased load on other VMs on the same physical machine. Especially on such low-profile VPS this can be quite a common problem.

Comment: Yeah, I think that too, and I will change this bad hoster to another host

Comment: Wait, I just had another look at your older screenshots. I think you sorted RES in ascending order. Your main issue seems to be the Apache server which spawns too many threads. Try reducing the number of threads. Also consider switching from prefork MPM to worker (see http://codebucket.co.in/apache-prefork-or-worker/ ). Apache is very resource hungry and can quickly gobble up your memory.

Comment: From what I can see on your screenshot, each thread had about 10MB from which parts may be shared. Sort RES in *descending* order and check for any other memory hogs.

Comment: Well, I've stopped apache server precedently, that's why the ram switched to ~600MB. With apache, the ram usage of the VPS is approx. 800 MB ! Also, I'm planning to switch to NGINX

Comment: How can I sort in descending order ?

Comment: Hit I (capital i) to reverse sort order. I also added a summary of this discussion to my answer above.

Comment: When I hit I, the sort order passed to ascending order. Apache2 service is stopped, but memory usage is still hight http://i.imgur.com/yRCVU4K.png

Comment: It's a toggle switch to switch between ascending and descending order. When there is no other single process that is using a lot of memory, it will be the sum of many processes. When RES is sorted correctly also make sure, you're at the beginning of the list (hit Pos1 on the keyboard).